# ASP.NET DataView - problem with RowFilter and application cache

Tags: asp.net, session, datatable, dataview, application-cache

Good afternoon ladies and gents --

I've been tasked with finding and fixing a bug in an unfamiliar legacy application that had some recent changes made to it, but I don't have an easy way (that I know of) to test my theory. I'm hoping your collective knowledge will verify the test for me.

This application lazy loads lookup lists (tongue-twister?) into `DataTable`s from a database and stores them as an object in `HttpContext.Current.Application` (an `HttpApplicationState`).

Before the changes were made, one of the lookup tables was bound to a `DropDownList` in the following manner (contrived):

```
Me._lookupList = TheSession.LookupCache.SomeLookupListName.DefaultView
...
ddl.DataSource = Me._lookupList
```

where 'SomeLookupListName' is a read-only property that returns a `DataTable` from `HttpContext.Current.Application`. The changes added some code that filters the private `Me._lookupList` (`DataView`) before being bound to the `DropDownList`:

```
Me._lookupList.RowFilter = "SomeTableIDColumn <> " & ...
```

What's happening, if you haven't guessed it already, is that that `DataView` is now filtered for every user of the application. I looked around the code and found that most other lookup lists are copied to local members in this fashion:

```
Me._lookupList = New DataView(TheSession.LookupCache.SomeLookupListName)
```

Since I don't know how to attack my local debug session pretending to be multiple users, will changing the code to use the latter method actually be any different than the former? Does filtering the result of `DataTable.DefaultView` actually apply the filter to the  underlying `DataTable` differently than if wrapping the table with a `New DataView(...)`?

Would it make sense to simply clear the row filter after the `DropDownList` is bound (seems like a bad solution)? I'd like to stick to the ugly conventions this application uses so that I don't surprise another developer down the road who gets a similar task, otherwise I'd just bypass the application state and grab the items right out of the data repository.

I appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does filtering the result of
>   DataTable.DefaultView actually apply
>   the filter to the underlying DataTable
>   differently than if wrapping the table
>   with a New DataView(...)?

Yes.  It creates a new view which the filter is applied to. The filter is not applied to the table directly.  Following the pattern to use the new view will work.

BTW, easy to test multiple sessions against your debugger.  Just open up two different browsers (IE and FF) and point to the same app.  User login might be the same, but the sessions will be unique.

Comment: Aye, I mistakenly thought IE shared session state between browser windows, but I think it's only tabs within the same window that share session. I pushed out a break fix with the new code; I'll come back and accept your answer if the problem goes away :)